# Resize img with server side or just with plain html

Tags: html, image, thumbnails, image-resizing

If I have images with `50 kB` and `450x450px` and I need to show the images in html only with `50x50px`, I have at least two options.

---

- Create thumbnails for each image with some server library, this implies save multiples images for each original image.
- Resize the original image :

  ```
  <img src="img.jpg" height="50" width="50">
  ```

What is best performance wise? Any considerations?

Comment: "Pros and cons" type questions aren't on topic on Stack Overflow I'm afraid. It's going to come down to size - whether it's a problem for you size wise to load a 450x450px image for each thumbnail, or not. There is no single answer to that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider a lot when coming to this subject, and there isn't a clear cut answer. It all depends on the frequency of use and the number of times an image changes.

Transferring an 8 MB image to the client is a horrible idea, as you imagine. Smaller images in high volume have the same effect. Putting through 100 images for a product page will yield a lot more data if you don't resize them server side.

It seems best to me to do the resizing server side. *Maybe* you can do it not on a per-request basis, but once when an image is uploaded / placed in the directory. This will yield the best performance.